# Regular expression to validate length string without including html tags

Tags: regex, umbraco

I am using umbraco where the validation on fields is done by regular expressions.  In one field I want to allow users to style their text using the rich text editor (tinymce) but I still want to limit the number of characters they can enter.

I'm currently using this regular expression but it checks the total number of characters so includes the html.

```
^[\s\S]{0,250}$
```

Is there a regular expression that wouldn't count the characters in html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. At least, not with any sane regex, not without an advanced regex engine that allows recursion or balanced groups, and maybe not at all. A regex that can recognize and ignore HTML tags would have to parse the HTML to do it, and [down that road lies madness.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

However, you *could* use some sort of preprocessing, such as jQuery on the client-side or something else on the server-side, to parse the HTML and strip out the tags *before* you apply length validation.

Are you sure you want to do this, though? If you're storing the styled input in a database, then those HTML tags are going to count against your column size just like everything else will. If you're storing these in a varchar(250) column, you're going to have to either count the HTML tags as part of that 250, or else strip them out and lose all the style information.

Comment: The limit is so it fits into a box with a set height.

Comment: Okay. In that case, I recommend using jQuery or something similar instead of regex. You can parse the HTML correctly that way, and you may even be able to set an onkeyup event that checks whether the box is full yet. Alternatively, you could make the box expandable if that's an option for you.

Comment: Either way, the problem with using regex to do this is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be hard (nigh impossible) to do this in one step, since the grammar you're trying to detect is <strike>not</strike> context-free. Two steps would be easy; just do a `s/<.+?>//` substitution first to remove all the tags then count again.

On a related note, your regex above is a little bit silly. You can use the `.` character to represent any character; you don't have to do the "whitespace OR not-whitespace" trick you're using.

```
^.{0,250}$
```

Comment: The `[\S\s]` trick is no doubt used to match `\n` characters. `.` will not match newlines unless multiline mode is turned on. Also, [HTML is context free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1758162#1758162), which is actually the problem. Context-free grammars are more complicated.

Comment: It's also probably worth mentioning that there's valid HTML that will break this regex. `<foo bar="a > b">`, for example. [The `>` symbol is allowed inside attributes.](http://mailman.ic.ac.uk/pipermail/xml-dev/1999-August/014064.html)

Comment: @Justin: ...and in JavaScript, there is no multiline mode, so `[\s\S]` is the common idiom for "any character, even newlines".